# Amazon qldb SELECT query to search specific rows with very less READIo's

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb, partiql

I have a table with the following columns

UserID (index),
SID (index),
Cause (index),
TimeValue (index),
Amount

I want to query the cause of a specific user id, Meaning I want some `cause` which is equal to let's say `water` but I want this for only one user whose id is 'someId'

The query that I have right now is doing a full table scan

`SELECT Cause, Cause_Amount, UserID FROM Contribution WHERE UserID = 'u5JvslEo9DbQ7hcq4vkM74dWlxr2' AND TimeValue > 1620414948000 AND ( Cause = 'cleanAir' OR Cause = 'safeWater')`

So the approach should be that it should target userId with the given id then check the TimeValue then the cause and return the result.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Is the `UID` in the query meant to be the `UserId` that you specify as having been indexed?

Comment: Yeah corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should put an index on your highest-cardinality document property. That means indexing on the property that is the most unique among your data. So if you have 10 users in your system but 1,000,000 documents in your `Contribution` table, that will need to scan 100,000 documents.

If you are seeing high read-IOs it is like because you have a small number of users but a large number of Contributions. It seems unlikely that `Cause` would be high-cardinality and QLDB does not yet (9/8/2021) support range queries and so the range query on `TimeValue` probably won't help either.

Are there other properties on your document that you could create an index on with higher cardinality?

Comment: My high cardinality property is UserID and maybe TimeValue. Basically TimeValue is time in digits i have generated it using ```new Date().getTime()```. What i was thinking that i want to see rows of specific UserID during a time where the cause is equal to water or something. I am using TimeValue with ```IN (startTimeValue, endTimeValue)``` let me share my updated incomplete query and a screenshot of table data. Cause check is missing in this query ```SELECT Cause, Cause_Amount, UID FROM ${tableName} WHERE UserId= 'ID' AND TimeValue IN (startTime, endTime)```. https://i.imgur.com/ISmr6BH.png

Comment: In your sample data there are only two unique user IDs and two different timestamps but 8 rows of data. In this case whichever index you pick would result in the same number of ReadIOs, which is 4.